# Issue with bloc_test and mockito when testing Flutter Bloc with a mocked repository

Tags: flutter, dart, testing, bloc

Question:

I'm facing an issue while trying to write unit tests for my Flutter application using the bloc_test library and mockito to mock a repository. The code structure includes a UserBloc that interacts with a UserRepository to fetch user data.

Problem:

When running the test, I encounter the error type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future'. This error seems to be related to using the MockUserRepository in my test. I've verified that the packages are up-to-date and support null safety.

```
// user_bloc_test.dart
import 'package:bloc_test/bloc_test.dart';
import 'package:elwan/core/blocs/user_bloc/user_bloc_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';

class MockUserRepository extends Mock implements UserRepository {}

void main() {
  group('UserBloc', () {
    late MockUserRepository mockUserRepository;

    setUp(() {
      mockUserRepository = MockUserRepository();
    });

    blocTest<UserBloc, UserState>(
      'emits [UserLoading, UserLoaded] when FetchUser is added successfully',
      build: () {
        when(mockUserRepository.fetchUserData())
            .thenAnswer((_) async => 'John Doe');
        return UserBloc(mockUserRepository);
      },
      act: (bloc) => bloc.add(FetchUser()),
      expect: () => [
        UserLoading(),
        UserLoaded('John Doe'),
      ],
    );

    blocTest<UserBloc, UserState>(
      'emits [UserLoading, UserError] when FetchUser fails',
      build: () {
        when(mockUserRepository.fetchUserData())
            .thenThrow(Exception('Failed to fetch'));
        return UserBloc(mockUserRepository);
      },
      act: (bloc) => bloc.add(FetchUser()),
      expect: () => [
        UserLoading(),
        UserError('Failed to fetch user data'),
      ],
    );
  });
}

// user_bloc.dart
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'dart:async';
part 'user_bloc_event.dart';
part 'user_bloc_state.dart';

class UserRepository {
  Future<String> fetchUserData() async {
    // Simulate a network request delay
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));

    // In a real application, this would make an actual network call
    // and parse the response.

    // For simplicity, we'll return a hardcoded value.
    return 'John Doe';
  }
}

class UserBloc extends Bloc<UserEvent, UserState> {
  final UserRepository userRepository;
  UserBloc(this.userRepository) : super(UserInitial()) {
    on<UserEvent>((event, emit) async {
      emit(UserLoading());
      try {
        final userData = await userRepository.fetchUserData();
        emit(UserLoaded(userData));
      } catch (e) {
        emit(UserError("Failed to fetch user data"));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Additional Information:

Flutter version: 3.10.0
bloc_test version: ^9.1.5
mockito version: ^5.0.0
Any other relevant information
What I've Tried:

Checked and updated the packages to their latest versions.
Reviewed the test setup and mocked repository usage.
Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: You should use mocktail with bloc_test